# Setting default filename in MS Word by automation

Tags: automation, ms-word

I'm trying to set the default folder and filename of a Word document by automation from Delphi. I don't want to save the document from my code. Rather, I want to set the defaults for when the user closes or actively saves the document.

I have searched all over and tried different things.

This have no effect for me:

```
Dialog := Application.Dialogs[wdDialogFileSummaryInfo];
Dialog.Title := 'MyFolderFilename'
```

This gives an error about BuiltInDocumentProperties not existing:

```
Application.ActiveDoument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyTitle).Value := 'MyFolderFilename';
```

But this one gets close:

```
Dialog := Application.FileDialog[msoFileDialogSaveAs];
Dialog.InitialFileName := 'MyFolderFilename';
Dialog.Show;
```

When calling Show my default shows up fine. However, if I don't call Show, my defaults are gone when closing or saving later. The same happens if I call Show but cancel the dialog.

Is there a way to "transfer" the defaults from this dialog to the one Word is showing later?

If I could "hook" the event for when the user saves or closes the document, maybe I could supress that dialog and show the one retrived by Application.FileDialog[msoFileDialogSaveAs]?

Comment: Word used to use the first piece of the text in the document as the default Title *and* the default file name but I don't think it has done that for a long time So not sure what you seek is possible unless you replace all the dialogs where Word requests the document path/name with your own dialogs. Not recommended! BTW your first piece of code just changes the title of a dialog box (not the document title) and your second needs something more like bidp :=  Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties; bidp[wdPropertyTitle].Value := 'myFolderFileName'; but with correct Delphi syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily store the default in a custom document property or document variable.

Then, you could follow one of these approaches:

1. When the user tries to save the document, you could test whether the variable **exists** and, if so, retrieve the stored default to populate the `FileSaveAs` dialogue. Then, if the document gets saved (regardless of whether the default is used), you can **delete the custom document property or document variable** (not just its contents).
2. When the user tries to save the document, you could test whether the variable **is empty** and, if not, retrieve the stored default to populate the `FileSaveAs` dialogue. Then, if the document gets saved (regardless of whether the default is used), you can **delete the contents** of the custom document property or document variable.

Comment: The essential difference is that you either create a temporary property/variable, which you delete when you're finished with it, or you the retain the property/variable in a populated/depopulated state.

Comment: Would this have to be done in a macro?

Comment: «Would this have to be done in a macro» Document variables can only be created and edited via code. Document properties can be created and edited via the GUI. The contents of both can be accessed via fields. Using them as suggested requires code, but you're already using code now to populate the variables you've been using. With this approach, a DocumentBeforeSave event in the document's template could be used to ensure the dialogue gets populated with default before it is first saved. For more events in Word, see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm